# Specialized data processing in C# to find instances of words in a string in textfile

Tags: c#, parsing, io

I have an example plaintext file called `dat` located in my example directory `/var/log/application/`. The structure would be something like this:

```
Cat
Dog
Bird
Fish
```

This is the data I want to analyze. I have a second file called `var` in the same directory containing a single line that says `I have a dog and a cat!`. With C#, I want to find the number of times words in `dat` are found in `var`. This should return a value of 2. To do this, I have written a mostly non-functional script in C# to explain my reasoning.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Systems.Collections.Generic;

namespace Example
{
     class Logic
     {
          static int instances;
          static int entries = GetDat();

          static string datpath = @"/var/log/application/dat";
          static string varpath = @"/var/log/application/var";

          static void Main(string[] args)
          {
               for(i = 0; i <= GetDat; i++)
               {
                    // I made this up because I don't know how to explain it otherwise
                    if(word.in GetVar instance.in GetDat)
                    {
                         instances++
                    }
                    return 2;
               }
          }

          static byte[] GetDat()
          {
               // Get entries from `dat` and turn it into array
          }

          static byte[] GetVar()
          {
               System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<String> lines = File.ReadLines(varpath);
          }
     }
}
```

How would I do this? Is there a more optimized way of doing this? This isn’t case sensitive and something like `doggen` would not return a result for `dog`. I do not need to stream anything with a StreamReader or StreamWriter and only ACSII text (“abcdefg”, not “82&:!:’ehebeodu”) is being processed. Any answers solving (or helping me solve) this problem would be appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: New code!

```
        public static void FindNumberOfSimilarStrings()
        {
            string[] var = StringOne();
            foreach(string line in StringTwo())
            {
                foreach(string entry in var)
                {
                    if (input.IndexOf(line, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(line);
                        instances++;
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(instances);
        }
```

Comment: Does this need to be fast, is memory a problem, is `dog` a match for `dogger`, is this case sensitive, what are the word boundary rules, does this need to deal with large files, do you need to stream this, what are the Unicode rules, etc, etc, etc, etc, etc. In short this question is a little bland and lacking sufficient constraints and needs a lot of clarification

Comment: @TheGeneral I’ve edited my question to fit the appropriate qualifications. It was my bad for not being specific enough. Next time I will not leave the details to be assumed. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace Example
{
    class Program
    {
        static int instances;
        static string datpath = @"/var/log/application/dat";
        static string varpath = @"/var/log/application/var";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string[] vs = GetVar();
            foreach (string line in GetDat())
            {
                foreach (string v in vs)
                {
                    if (v.IndexOf(line, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(line);
                        instances++;
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"instances = {instances}");
        }

        static string[] GetDat()
        {
            return File.ReadAllLines(datpath);
        }

        static string[] GetVar()
        {
            return File.ReadAllLines(varpath);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work as this seemingly compares 'Var' with nothing for how many entries are in 'Dat'. Could you elaborate?